# How i can open a splashtop app from my own app in android

Tags: java, android, eclipse, android-layout

Can anyone please help me to open a splashtop app from my own app. I installed splashtop and created an account in it. In my app, i have a field for entering the username and password and also an ok button. By entering  the username and password of splashtop acount in my own app, when i press ok button, it will go the original splashtop app. Please help me for creating this. Thanks in Advance.

Please anyone help me for that.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution for that, we can do it by

```
Intent LaunchIntent = 
    getPackageManager().getLaunchIntentForPackage("com.splashtop.remote.pad.v2");
startActivity(LaunchIntent);
```

Answer (score 0):

This will help you, its for moving from one activity of one application to another activity of another application.

```
final Intent intent = new Intent();

ComponentName cActname = new ComponentName
("package_name","package_name.class_name");

intent.setComponent(cActname);         
startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: Thanx for giving me the reply. But how can i found the package name of the splashtop android app??? Please give me the reply.

Comment: You can only shift to those applications that you know the package name of(which means they have to be created by you). 
You can't just go and access other applications its not allowed in Android.

Comment: Actually i need to access the splashtop android app. I have downloaded the app in my android device and created an account using an username and password. And i have  an app with a field of username, password and an ok button. When i enter the username and password that i was used to create splashtop in my app, it will go to the splashtop android app. That is i needed. Is it possible??? That was my question, please help me for that.

Comment: No its not possible. You can redirect him to the website of Splashtop using webview but you can't redirect him to any application unless you know its package name and only the developer of that application would know its package name.